# PayPal Invalid Client error with Postman - Sandbox Mode

Tags: paypal, postman, paypal-sandbox

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to make my first call using API with Postman to paypal and I'm getting an error. I've followed the steps. I'm logged into my developer account on paypal, I created a new test account called "uokgames1". Any information would be great. I'm trying to find video tuts as well but nothing useful so far.

username: uokgames1@gmail.com
Password: not sure if I can share the password or not. I'll ask before I post it.

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you need more detail? I have not seen any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think i got it working but I want to share the answer with everyone. This worked for me but I may not have the best answer but I hope it helps you.

Step 1:
You need to create a dummy app and account linked to it.
[image]

Step 2: 
Get your sandbox credentials 
[image]

Step 3
Enter the information in Postman. You want to use the Client ID as your username and use the secret as your password. Select Post and use x-www-form-urlencoded. 
[image]

Step 4
Click Send and you should get a response message with your token.